# watchdog: BUG: Soft lockup - CPU stuck. Linux Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, wsl

Estaba cambiando la versión del wsl1 a wsl2, para ello tuve que instalar una actualización del kernel de Linux. No sé que pasó exactamente, pero luego de realizar las configuraciones necesarias para cambiar la versión del wsl, mi máquina virtual kali linux dejó de funcionar. Ahora en la ventana de arranque me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde la configuración avanzada traté de ejecutar otra versión del kernel pero tampoco funciona:
[image: Esto es lo único que me aparece en configuración avanzada]

Error ejecutando la otra versión del kernel:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desinstalé y reinstalé tanto Virtual Box como Kali pero no he podido solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo ejecutas en el host y, si es Linux, cuál kernel?

Comment: Mi SO principal es Windows 10, el kernel de mi Kali linux (VM) es 5.16.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juga con la cantidad de CPUS (proba en 1) y Memoria.
En algunos casos la aceleracion 3D da problemas, podes desactivarla.Tribolco08

Comment: Amigo gracias, me ayudaste mucho. En mi caso sólo fué necesario bajar la cantidad de procesadores a 1. Estoy muy agradecido UwU